# Dados de form não são enviados com event.preventDefault()

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, mvc

Ao submeter um formulário, estou utilizando *ajax* e `event.preventDefault()` para que a tela não seja recarregada. No meu projeto, fiz uma pequena estrutura MVC, onde a URL que passo é o caminho que leva até o controlador desejado.

Quando submeto o formulário via POST sem `event.preventDefault()` tudo funciona normalmente. Mas quando coloco tal código, nada acontece no sistema, como se os dados do form não fossem enviados. Estou quebrando a cabeça com isso.

Segue o trecho do código:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('form').submit(function(event){ 
            var formDados = jQuery(this).serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type        : 'POST', 
                url         : 'http://127.0.0.1/projeto/index.php?path=capacitacao/adm',
                data        : formDados,
                dataType    : 'json',
                encode      : true,
                success:function(result){
                    console.log(result);
                }
            })
            event.preventDefault();

    });
});
```

Comment: O motivo certamente que não terá a ver com o `preventDefault`. O `console.log(result);` no `success` corre ? Se não correr experimente implementar o *handler* de erro com `error: function(a, b, c) { console.log(a,b,c); }` e veja o resultado

Comment: Consegui visualizar a mensagem de erro fazendo essa alteração. Agora irei tentar resolver o erro que apareceu: parsererror" SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Answer (score 0):

Tenta assim, substitui o "success" pelo "done" e adicionei o "fail", você pode tirar a "action" do seu formulário assim quando ativar o "submit" ele nao tera para onde ir.

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('form').submit(function(event){

            event.preventDefault();

            var formDados = $(this).serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type        : 'POST', 
                url         : 'http://127.0.0.1/projeto/index.php?path=capacitacao/adm',
                data        : formDados

            }).done(function(response){

                 console.log(response);

            }).fail(function(result) {

                  console.log(result);

            });
});
```

Comment: Consegui visualizar a mensagem de erro: parsererror" SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: tira esse e argumentos, dataType e encode

Comment: Deu certo. Obrigada!!